# How to play a Spotify track without libspotify?

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, spotify

I'm currently writing an embedded C++/Qt/GStreamer application.  I don't want to use the deprecated libspotify. I only see search info in the web API but no way to actually play tracks.

Does anyone know how to do that?  I have a developer clientID and ClientSecret id's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm in a much similar situation. Could you find any viable solution? I thought about using the web api for everything except the play part, but I guess it's not possible to login twice.

Comment: Sorry for the great delay in replying.  I do have code if you still want it.

Comment: Forgive me for ressurrecting this post but how did you solve this problem? I too want to play the tracks in a Qt desktop app but found no information on how to do that.